# Force translation into certain language with angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have two translations for my app, English and German, but I need my invoicing module to use a separate language setting.

Is there a way to force the labels on the invoicing page to use the language I set in the `invoice_language` variable?

So instead of

```
{{ 'TD_ID' | translate }}
```

I need something like

```
{{ 'TD_ID' | translate:'{"language": invoice_language}' }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your TD_ID only once in your controller swapping the language before you do so.

In your view, instead of:

```
{{ 'TD_ID' | translate }}
```

simply bind without translate filter:

```
{{ 'TD_ID' }}
```

and in your controller:

```
function setInvoiceTranslations(key){
  var invoice_language = 'de';
  currentLang = $translate.use();
  $translate.use(invoice_language);
  var translateText;
  $translate(key).then(function (translatedtext) {
    $scope[key] = translatedtext;
    $translate.use(currentLang);
  });

}

setInvoiceTranslations('TD_ID');
```

To see this in action see [***this plunker***](http://plnkr.co/edit/bUJvMIG6PMYdM2Ys12T2?p=preview) (which adapts [the "How it works" example from angular-translate.github.io](https://angular-translate.github.io/)).

See [this page on angular-translate's docs](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service) for information about this technique (please read ["Things to keep in mind" on that page](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service#using-$translate-service_things-to-keep-in-mind)).

(make sure you inject $translate into your controller, or where-ever you end up putting the setInvoiceTranslations() function)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was backed up with other tasks. The weird thing about this is that it only works for me if I put `$translate.use(currentLang);` inside `then`, otherwise it uses the current language when entering `then` I have no idea why. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem with your late response :) and, silly me - you can modify my answer, if you would like, to put the $translate.use(currentLang); where you have correctly moved it to, because I have introduced a race condition with my code and your revision solves this.  I will accept the edit once I see you have completed it.  thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: just to be clearer about the race condition - the code after the `$translate(key).then` call will run immediately after that line and could well run before the promise (the `.then(function[...])` callback is run.  This is what is happening for you, but didn't happen in my plunker code and my brain didn't think it through properly before I committed it to SO.

Comment: @Norbert I have updated the Plunker since you can't get rep for that edit! :)

Comment: I suspected that was the reason for not working in my controller, but I kept wondering how come it worked in Plunker. Maybe it has to do with the size of the translation file. Thanks again for the assist!

Comment: yes, I suspect file size could well have caused the currentLang to reset before the promise returned - sorry I missed that and caused a degree of debug work.  Glad to help.

Comment: btw: If you call setInvoiceTranslations multiple times in succession, bear in mind that currentLang might not work as you expect due to the race condition... in that case you might be best to not pass in `key` but to use some other mechanism.  However, your question only mentions TD_ID so I am adding this comment for others primarily...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom filter (ex. "wordKey" | translateTo: languageKey ) and call the $translate service:

```
.filter('translateTo', function ($translate) {
  return function (key, lang) {
   return $translate.instant(key, {}, undefined, lang);
  }; });
```

You can force the word to be translated on the fly without modifying the global language.

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate

Answer (score 0):

Let follow this doc: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate
You can translate a text to a specific language with `forceLanguage` param;
For example:

```
$translate('PUSH_NOTIFICATION.NEW_RATING', {}, undefined, undefined, 'ar').then(function (translatedText) {
     if(translatedText){
         ..do something
 });  

//'PUSH_NOTIFICATION.NEW_RATING' is Translate KEY in your language file
// {}  for dynamic values
// 'ar' a specific language
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using angular-translate's built in `translate-language` directive as so:

```
<div translate-language="{{ invoice_language }}">
    {{ 'TD_ID' | translate }}
</div>
```

No need to create a custom one or do anything in the controller.

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translateLanguage